# Extending the lim function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, descriptive-set-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\omega$ denote the set of non-negative integers. Let $A$ denote the set of all sequences of numbers from $[0, 1]$ that converge. We have thus a well defined function $l\colon A \to [0, 1]$, where

$$l((x_i)_{i<\omega}) = \lim_{i\to\infty} x_i.$$

I'd like to extend this function $l$ to the set of all sequences of numbers from $[0, 1]$, we assume the product topology here, such that it will be $\Sigma_2^0$ measurable, i.e. the preimage of an open set will be a $\Sigma_2^0$ set. Equivalently, a Baire 1 function (pointwise limit of continuous functions).

The problem is that I can only show that $A$ is a $\Pi_3^0$ set. If I could show it is $\Pi_2^0$, the extension would be possible.

It is quite possible that $l$ cannot be extended in this way but I don't see that proof either.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT:** The function $l$ is $\Sigma_2^0$ measurable on the set $A$. It is the pointwise limit of continuous functions, namely
$$l((x_i)_{i<\omega}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{proj}_n((x_i)_{i<\omega}),$$
where $\mathrm{proj}_n((x_i)_{i<\omega}) = x_n$.

Comment: Note that the set of sequences with limit $0$ has in its pointwise closure a sequence with limit $1$.  So with the product topology your functional is of course not continuous.  On the other hand, using a Hamel basis, any linear functional extends to something (in general discontinuous).

Comment: @GEdgar the important thing is whether it is $\Sigma^0_2$ measurable, of course I can extend that function to every sequence by for example assigning the zero value to divergent sequences but what I need is the extension to be well-behaved in the sense of being $\Sigma^0_2$ measurable

Comment: @GEdgar about that continuity, yes it is not continuous; however, I can show it is a Baire $1$ function, it can be approximated by the projection function, thus it is $\Sigma^0_2$ measurable

Answer (score 1):

There is the notion of Banach limit $\text{Lim}$. This is a linear functional defined on the space of all *bounded* sequences $B(\mathbb{R})$ which for convergent sequences coincides with lim.

Comment: And for students of functional analysis, the proof is easy, starting with the recipe "Hahn-Banach theorem".

Comment: I am aware of this notion but is this extension $\Sigma^0_2$ measurable?